# How did Julia and Quentin return in the middle of The Magician King?

Tags: lev-grossman, the-magicians

I've been trying to figure this out, but I must have missed some little key detail. Here's what I know for sure.

> Quentin and Julia are traveling through Fillory, exploring the islands. By the power of the magic keys, they accidentally return to Earth. After 3 days of trying to get back, they finally end up at the place where people were first able to go to Fillory, and somehow after a whole day of searching end up back at Fillory, first trying each of the methods outlined in the books for entering the place.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They end up going back to the Chatwin's house where they spend the night...

> Playing games with a young boy and getting very drunk... After a bout of the bed spins they find themselves back in Fillory...

The scene illustrates two points:  Quentin has hit rock bottom, he finally gives up his *childish* need to return to Fillory and begins to imagine life as an adult, with a wife and family, in this world.  Firmly planted back on Earth, playing games with a little boy, Quentin and his friends recapture the *childlike* (innocence?) magic that initially drew them to Fillory...